# Deleting characters from a string

Tags: c++

I am trying to delete certain characters from a string.

My code is:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    string x = "hello";
    string y = "ell";

    string result = x.erase( x.find(y), (x.find(y)) + y.length() - 1 );
    cout << result << endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

and it gives the desired output of:

```
ho
```

But when I change the strings to

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    string x = "Xx";
    string y = "Xx";

    string result = x.erase( x.find(y), (x.find(y)) + y.length() - 1 );
    cout << result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

it prints out

```
x
```

Instead of the desired output of nothing. I believe it has something to do with the way erase(), find(), and length() all count characters (from 0 or from 1) but I couldn't find anything in the documentation. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use first variant of [std::string::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase)

> basic_string& erase( size_type index = 0, size_type count = npos );

second parameter is count not position, so just use `y.length()`:

```
string result = x.erase( x.find(y), y.length() );
```

it "works" in first case from your example in coincidence.

[live example](https://ideone.com/Tv3aKJ)